# Find remainder of large non-exponential integer divided by 180

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers

Find the remainder when $12345678910111213...20172018$ is divided by $180$.

$$12345678910111213...20172018 \quad \text{mod} \quad 180$$

The large dividend is formed by writing all the natural numbers up to 2018 together.

---

I've read some posts similar on the community. And they took an approach some sort like this:

$$\text{Let } a=12345678910111213...20172018$$

$$180 =4\times5\times9$$
$$a\text{ mod }4 = 2$$
$$a\text{ mod }5 = 3$$
$$a\text{ mod }9 = 3$$
So $$a\text{ mod }180 = 2\times3\times3=18$$

I know there is definitely something wrong with my method, though I can't recall where I saw it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the three congruences: $a\equiv 2\pmod 4,
a\equiv 3\pmod 5, a\equiv 3\pmod 9$. Next you need to use the Chinese remainder theorem (twice) using Bezout formulas. First $$4*(-1)+1*5=1,$$ so $$a\equiv 4*(-1)*3+1*5*2=-2  \pmod{4*5}.$$ Then $$20*(-4)+9*9=1,$$ so $$a\equiv 20*(-4)*3+9*9*(-2)=-402\equiv 138 \pmod{20*9}$$
**Answer**:138.

Comment: Sorry, took a while to learn the Bezout Identity, though I still don't understand how CRT and the Bezout formulas are implemented in your solution. May you explain it in your solution?

Comment: This is a standard proof of the Chinese remainder theorem. If $m, n$ are relatively prime and $mu+nv=1$ ($u,v$ are Bezout coefficients). Then for every integers $s, t$ the number $mut+nvs$ is $\equiv s\pmod m$ and $\equiv t \pmod n$. Moreover there exists unique $\pmod{mn}$ integer $a$ such that $a\equiv s\pmod m, a\equiv t\pmod n$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(constructive_proof)